# Bad redirect from facebook - can't log in as admin to fix

Tags: facebook

Sorry this is a n00bish question, but desperate times... I'm an admin on a Facebook page, been up for years. I'm consistently getting a redirect to what appears to be a page related to Facebook's GDPR "changes." I use the word 'changes' loosely - I have no idea what this is about. Now, I'm personally admining the page from Ireland, for an organization based in the US, I don't know if that matters.

This all worked up until a couple days ago. I change nothing, but now I get 'too many redirects', from every browser I try on various computers (Chrome, Firefox, even Edge.) Yes, all running Win10.

Here are some of the pages that come up, can't quite discern the loop but it seems like the problems with the 'facebook.com/gdpr' page, which I think is bogus, somehow. 
https://www.facebook.com/pages/American-Killifish-Association/441507139269126
https://www.facebook.com/gdpr/consent/?consent_mode=5&entry_product=cg_block&from_messenger=0
https://www.facebook.com/upgradeaccount/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fgdpr%2Fconsent%2F%3Fconsent_mode%3D5%26entry_product%3Dcg_block%26from_messenger%3D0

https://www.facebook.com/pages/manage
https://www.facebook.com/gdpr/consent/?consent_mode=5&entry_product=cg_block&from_messenger=0
....

Am I correct in assuming that the problem's on Facebook's side? Could there be something in my pages config (it's a dirt simple page) that's causing this? And, as admin, how can I fix this since I can't log in! Thanks for your patience in reading this.

Comment: Hello Matt, I have the same issue right now. Exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: You must be using a dedicated email to login into this page, like not having this page linked to any regular FB profile I believe. I'm assuming this as that's the case for me. My guess is that FB requires the agreement of the user for managing the page but the user being not attached to a FB profile it can't pass the stage.

Comment: Same problem for me. Anyone?

Comment: FWIW, I was able to log into the page from an Android phone - it's apparently mostly ignoring the redirects. I put Fb on the phone and signed in via the dedicated email account. I can add and delete posts now, but FB on android doesn't let me add administrators as far as I can tell. Nor can I find anything about redirects. And of course, I have not heard from Facebook, I wonder if they ever reply to anyone on anything.

Comment: so I am also using the Android FB page App and post stuff there. Not perfect but works. I also escalated the bug to FB.

Comment: Same issue here. I could login from the mobile site and the mobile app (ios). In mobile site I can't do posts or see the feed, it shows an error message "page unavailable". In the mobile app I can see the feed but the page keeps reloading. Messenger also doesn't seem to work, it keeps disconnecting and reconnecting. I've contacted FB through the help center, but  out f luck thus far.

Comment: Same here, still trying to solve the issue. Facebook haven't done anything yet to contend the issue.

Comment: @user2929613 Where did you report the bug? Perhaps we can add some me toos to speed things up a bit.

Comment: it is now fixed!

Comment: Miracle of Facebook, it appears to be fixed. Must've been 'by design' and slow to roll out.@user2929613 how *do* you escalate with Facebook?

Comment: It's 2020 now .. .and still the same problem... Great F Facebook !

Comment: Somehow the "LOGIN ON YOUR MOBILE" is a very good workaround anyway.